# How to pipe the results of 'find' to mv in Linux

Tags: linux, unix

How do I pipe the results of a 'find' (in Linux) to be moved to a different directory? This is what I have so far.

```
find ./ -name '*article*' | mv ../backup
```

but its not yet right (I get an error missing file argument, because I didn't specify a file, because I was trying to get it from the pipe)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Linux why can't I pipe find result to rm?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20307299/linux-why-cant-i-pipe-find-result-to-rm)

Comment: Ok, its not exact duplicate, but there is also an answer :)

Answer (score 92, accepted):

```
find ./ -name '*article*' -exec mv {}  ../backup  \;
```

OR

```
find ./ -name '*article*' | xargs -I '{}' mv {} ../backup
```

Comment: when I ran your second command, it says xargs: invalid option -- I. What is wrong here? I see that it is a valid option on the man page.

Comment: @user1015214 - Is none of the 4 commands on this page working for you?

Comment: no. If it helps, I am in a git Bash on a windows machine. It seems to be running linux commands, but I guess it doesn't have the full library?

Comment: @user1015214 - Probably git bash is limited. Since you are on windows machine, I'd suggest using `Move-Item Cmdlet` in `Powershell`. You can do `Move-Item *article* \full\path\to\backup`

Answer (score 43):

`xargs` is commonly used for this, and `mv` on Linux has a `-t` option to facilitate that.

```
find ./ -name '*article*' | xargs mv -t ../backup
```

If your `find` supports `-exec ... +` instead of `-exec ... \;` you could equivalently do

```
find ./ -name '*article*' -exec mv -t ../backup {} +
```

The `-t` option is a GNU extension, so it is not portable to systems which do not have GNU `coreutils` (though every proper Linux I have seen has that, with the possible exception of Busybox). For complete POSIX portability, it's of course possible to roll your own replacement, maybe something like

```
find ./ -name '*article*' -exec sh -c 'mv "$@" "$0"' ../backup {} +
```

where we shamelessly abuse the convenient fact that the first argument after `sh -c 'commands'` ends up as the "script name" parameter in `$0` so that we don't even need to `shift` it.

Probably see also https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/020

Comment: When I tried you first suggestion, it said 'invalid option -- t'. When I tried your second one, it said -exec command not found, so I guess its not supported.

Comment: Sounds like you are not on Linux after all then, as this has been supported by the GNU versions of these tools for a long time.  I can't find (sic) a `find` which doesn't support `-exec` in *some* form -- maybe you mistyped the command?

Comment: Actually Busybox supports `mv -t` too.

Comment: Note if you use this, your directories cannot have spaces in them.

Comment: @exclowd The `find -exec` variant is specifically robust against all kinds of problems with unusual file names. The `xargs` variant is slightly less so, though the linked FAQ has a more elaborate variation which requires GNU `find` (so basically Linux only). In brief, `find ... -print0 | xargs -r0 mv -t ../backup`

Answer (score 3):

I found this really useful having thousands of files in one folder:

```
ls -U | head -10000 | egrep '\.png$' | xargs -I '{}' mv {} ./png
```

To move all pngs in first 10000 files to subfolder png

Comment: The regex has no `egrep` (aka `grep -E` more modernly) syntax, and you can factor out the `head`: `grep -m 10000 '\.png$'`, More generally you should [avoid `ls` in scripts](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs),

Comment: Perhaps then `printf '%s\0' *.png | xargs -r0 mv -t png/` which avoids the various issues with `ls`, and `printf '%s\0' *.png | grep -z -m 10000 ^ | xargs -r0 mv -t png/` to coincidentally use `grep -z -m` *items* as a replacement for `head` which groks null-terminated input. The link I posted earlier explains these things in much more detail. I'm divided about improving an answer which advocates `ls`; but feel free to update as you see fit, and include anything or everything from these comments. Incidentally, `xargs -0` is GNU only (should work on Linux, but isn't properly portable).

Answer (score 0):

```
mv $(find . -name '*article*') ../backup
```

Comment: this command is not correct. it says `missing file operand`. (I used -t before ../backup to define the destination directory)

Comment: It's working for me. Your backup directory should be placed back to your search directory.

Comment: This is susceptible to generating invalid file names. The command substitution to generate the list of source file names is inherently problematic. It will look like it's working if you test it on the trivial cases, but it will break horribly if you have filenames with spaces or shell metacharacters in them. Several items on https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashPitfalls are variations of this FAQ.

Answer (score 0):

Here are a few solutions.

```
find . -type f -newermt "2019-01-01" ! -newermt "2019-05-01" \
    -exec mv {} path \;**
```

or

```
find path -type f -newermt "2019-01-01" ! -newermt "2019-05-01" \
    -exec mv {} path \;
```

or

```
find /Directory/filebox/ -type f -newermt "2019-01-01" \
    ! -newermt "2019-05-01" -exec mv {} ../filemove/ \;
```

The backslash + newline is just for legibility; you can equivalently use a single long line.

Answer (score -1):

`xargs` is your buddy here (When you have multiple actions to take)!

And using it the way I have shown will give great control to you as well.

```
find ./ -name '*article*' | xargs -n1 sh -c "mv {}  <path/to/target/directory>"
```

**Explanation:**

1. `-n1`

Number of lines to consider for each operation ahead

2. `sh -c`

The shell command to execute giving it the lines as per previous condition

3. `"mv {} /target/path"`

The move command will take two arguments-

1) The line(s) from operation 1, i.e. {}, value substitutes automatically

2) The target path for move command, as specified

**Note: the "Double Quotes" are specified to allow any number of spaces or arguments for the shell command which receives arguments from xargs**

Comment: Why would you require `-n1` and what is then the purpose of the `sh -c` wrapper? This onl. brings drawbacks compared to the other, older, similar answers.

Comment: Thank you for the feedback. I have been using this syntax for quite some time. Can you enlighten me on the drawbacks? It will only help me be better informed

Comment: The `sh -c` is useless if you only ever loop over a single argument. On the other hand, the `-n 1` is basically making `xargs` useless too; just run `find -exec` if you only move one file at a time. Processing only one file at a time is hugely wasteful, though; you should generally attempt to minimize the number of subprocesses.  The previous answers implement various optimizations to do exactly that, some more aggressively and robustly than others.